# How can i get this value in this variable [Linux Bash]

Tags: linux, bash

Can i get this value in this variable [Linux Bash]
my code

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=1
"user$COUNTER"=text
echo "$user$COUNTER"
```

result : 1
i need result : text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, working with dynamic variable names like you want will only make your life more difficult. Arrays are much easier to work with (even in bash with it's picky syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
declare -a user   # this line is optional
user[$counter]=text
echo "${user[$counter]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is eval

```
eval user$COUNTER=text
```

Output:

```
/home/shellter:>eval "user$COUNTER"=text
/home/shellter:>echo $user1
text
```

Eval performs variable evaluations any visible variables on the command line, and then 'resubmits' the results to normal command-line evaluation and processing.

You can see some of this happening (once you have worked with for a while it will become obvious) by turning on the shell debugging with `set -vx`.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: You also need to `eval echo $user$COUNTER` -- you have to eval any time you want to dereference the "compound" variable.